# .NET Web Api 2 UserPrincipal.IsAuthenticated always false when using dependency injection (Unity)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a custom authorization attribute which verifies token inside header and sets user-principal.

```
 //when token is validated
var userIdentityBase = new UserIdentityBase(token); <-- Inherited GenericIdentity
IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentityBase, null);

actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

This works fine when I check for Identity inside controller 
[image]

But when i inject IPrincipal to my service classes, it does not work anymore. `IsAuthenticated` is false.

Unity setup code:

```
 container.RegisterType<IPrincipal>(new InjectionFactory(u => HttpContext.Current.User));
```

When injected, it does not work (both screenshots are taken withing same request):
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The dependency resolver is resolving the dependencies on application start. There are no current user at that time

Comment: @MarcusH so there is no way to inject user principal at runtime?

Comment: I don't think there is, but I have no facts to support that. I have solved this issue before by passing the user as a parameter or setting a static variable to current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by creating own interface and implementation, which will extract user identity at runtime. Works like a charm for my case

Interface

```
public interface IIdentityProvider
{
   IPrincipal GetPrincipal();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class IdentityProvider : IIdentityProvider
{
    public IPrincipal GetPrincipal()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

unity registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IIdentityProvider, IdentityProvider>();
```

And usage:

```
IIdentityProvider _identityProvider;
public BookingRecordService(IIdentityProvider identityProvider)
{
    _identityProvider = identityProvider;

    var isAuth = _identityProvider.GetPrincipal().Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just posting code.